# EasyOCR not recognizing simple numbers

Tags: python, ocr, data-conversion, scanning

I am trying to analyze a page footer in a video and retrieve the current page number. I got the frame collection working but I am struggling on reading the page number itself, using EasyOCR.

I already tried using pytesseract, but that doesnt work well. I have misinterpreted numbers: 10 gets recognized as 113, 6 as 41 and so on. Overall its very inconsistent, even though I format my input image correctly with grayscale, threshholding and cropping (only analyzing the pagenumber area of the footer).

Here is the code:

```
def getPageNumberTest(path, psm):
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    height = len(image)
    width = len(image[0])
    # the height of the footer
    footerHeight = 90 # int(height / 15.5)
    # retrieve only the footer from the image
    cropped = image[height-footerHeight:height,0:width]        

    results = reader.readtext(cropped)
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image]

Is there a setting I am missing? Is there a way to instruct EasyOCR to look for numbers only?
Any help or hint is appreciated!

EDIT:

After some fiddling around with some optimizations of the number-images, I am now back to the beginning, not optimizing the images at all. All thats left is the conversion to gray-scale and a resize.

This is what a normal input looks like:

[image: input image]

But the results are:

[image: output results]

Which is weird, because for most numbers (especially for single digits) this works flawlessly, yielding certainties of over 95%...

I tried deblurring, threshholding, denoising with cv2.filter2D(), blurring,...

When I use threshholding, for example, my output looks like this (ignoring the "1", same applies for the single digit "1"):

[image: results when using threshholding]

I had a look into pattern matching, which isnt an option because I don't know the pagenumber shape beforehand...

Comment: Try this, https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR/issues/130.

Comment: I tried that, output is still inconsistent

Comment: Please add unmodified original image to your question and also try with higher resolution image if possible.

Comment: I edited my question. I cant get a higher resolution because the pages are taken from a video...

Comment: What is your kernel numbers, in the cv2, to have the last image?

Answer (score 0):

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(final_image, config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, PaddleOCR works better than easyOCR in most scenes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).